# In the makefile script: *.c and $(wildcard *.c) are different?I am confused by my experiments

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

## experiment 1

```
CC = gcc
src = *.c#$(wildcard *.c)
obj = $(src:.c=.o)
target = $(src:.c=.exe)
$(target) : $(obj)

%.exe : $(obj)
    $(CC) $< -o $@
%.o : $(src)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
clean:
    rm *.exe *.o
```

## experiment 2

```
src = *.c
src1 = $(wildcard *.c)

p :
    @echo $(src)
p1 :
    @echo $(src1)
```

In experiment 1, `*.c` and `$(wildcard *.c)` has a big difference.
if `src` (a variable) = `*.c`, gcc will gives me a error as follows:

> ```
>        gcc -c test1.c -o *.o
>        Assembler messages:
>        Fatal error: can't create *.o: Invalid argument
>        makefile:25: recipe for target '*.o' failed
>        make: *** [*.o] Error 1
> ```

If i replace `*.c` with `$(wildcard *.c)`, everything goes well.

In experiment 2, `*.c` and `$(wildcard *.c)` has a no difference in result.

```
   if @echo $(src)
           echo file1.c file2.c file3.c
   if @echo $(src1)
           echo file1.c file2.c file3.c
```

ADDITIONS:There are 3 c file for testing.

Comment: Try `@echo '$(src)'`. In that case, it's the sheel that expands the `*`, because you didn't add quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wildcard` function is evaluated by `make` when it is expanded.

The string `*.c` is just a string, as far as make is concerned.  So this line:

```
obj = $(src:.c=.o)
```

if `src` is `$(wildcard *.c)` then make will first expand `src` into `foo.c bar.c baz.c` then replace the `.c` with `.o`, giving `foo.o bar.o baz.o`.

If `src` is `*.c`, then make will expand `src` but it's just the simple string `*.c` so no expansion is needed, then it replaces `.c` with `.o`, giving `*.o`.

This rule is wrong, too:

```
%.o : $(src)
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

they says "every individual object file depends on ALL the source files" which is not what you want.

Comment: It is my honor to view your useful ans.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have told Make that any file ending in `.exe` depends on `$(obj)`.  If `src = *.c`, then `obj = *.o` so Make tries to compile that.

Any file ending `.o` depends on `$(src)`, which is `*.c`, so Make attempts to compile `*.c` and produce a file called `*.o` - that's the command it echoed:

```
       gcc -c *.c -o *.o
```

For some reason (perhaps a very limited filesystem type), GCC can't write the `*.o` file.

When you use the `$(wildcard)` function in Make, then it gets expanded to multiple tokens.

---

As an aside, you probably meant

```
%.o: %.c
```

But you should avoid writing rules that duplicate (badly) the built-in rules.  Just trust Make to know how to use `CC`, `CFLAGS` and the rest.